# How to emulate Postgresql EXCEPT operator in rails scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I've got a SQL query

```sql
SELECT * FROM students
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM students WHERE val->>'rating' = 'Fail'
```

How can I achieve the same result in a Rails scope?

Comment: you can rewrite that as a `where not exists` condition. Maybe your obfuscation layer can handle that.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM students WHERE val->>'rating' <> 'Fail'`

Comment: @Edouard This query doesn't work out for me. It's not the same as the one I specified. I also need records with non existing rating key.

Comment: @Alex Shmatko : OK, let's try this : `SELECT * FROM students WHERE val->>'rating' IS DISTINCT FROM 'Fail'`, this query should include the records with non existing 'rating' key

Comment: @Edouard Great stuff! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM students
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM students WHERE val->>'rating' = 'Fail'
```

equals to

```rb
Student.where("val->>'rating' IS DISTINCT FROM ?", 'Fail')
```